# jQuery: How to Exact Match Div Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jquery, I did try to find things online and this is what I have come up with. Need help to achieve below scenario :

How do I write a jQuery to exactly match each of these below?

```
div class="plugin-container plugin-news_home_feature"

div class="plugin-container plugin-news_home_feature plugin-section-wrapper"
```

No matter what I do when I write code for the first div class above the second is also captured

I've tried these but none are working

```
jQuery(".plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature")

jQuery(div[class="plugin-container plugin-news_home_feature"])

jQuery(".plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature").not(".plugin-container plugin-news_home_feature.plugin-section-wrapper")
```

I tried with the periods between each plugin and without and nothing is working for me.

Thanks in advance

---Update---

So what I'm trying to do is capture an event with Google Tag Manager but the events are being captured in the same bucket so to speak. Here is what I have.

```
    $("div.plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature").not('div.plugin-section-wrapper').on('click', function (e) {
  dataLayer.push({
        event: 'homeTracking',
        action: 'Featured Stories under First Hero'
    });
});


jQuery(".plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature.plugin-section-wrapper").on('click', function (e) {
  dataLayer.push({
        event: 'homeTracking',
        action: 'First Read Feature'
    });
});
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely separate languages.

Comment: how about just `jQuery('.plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature:not(.plugin-section-wrapper)')`?

Comment: `jQuery(".plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature").not('.plugin-section-wrapper');`

Answer (score 1):

You would use the **[`:not()` CSS pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** in your JQuery selector to exclude the one you don't want.

```js
$("div.plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature:not(div.plugin-section-wrapper)").addClass("test");
```

```css
.test { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plugin-container plugin-news_home_feature">First Div</div>

<div class="plugin-container plugin-news_home_feature plugin-section-wrapper">Second Div</div>
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. I updated my question to add more context

Comment: Well, you're not actually using my code (I'm using the CSS `:not()` pseudo-class and you are using the JQuery `.not()` method). Either way, the issue is not with the selector. Both will work as you can see from running my code. The issue has got to be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$("div.plugin-container.plugin-news_home_feature").not("div.plugin-section-wrapper");
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. I updated my question to add more context.